# Why did post fail in my Rails functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

When I run a post in my Rails functional test

```
setup do
  post :create, :user => Factory.attributes_for(:user)
end
```

and it fails, I don't get any feedback as to why.  I know that it fails because my assertion to make sure that there's one additional record in the database fails.

I tried to do

```
setup do
  post :create, :user => Factory.attributes_for(:user)
  assert_valid @controller.object
end
```

but object is a protected method.

How can I examine the errors on the model object that results from the post call?

I'm using Shoulda and Factory Girl, but I suspect that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following assertion:

```
assert_nil assigns(:user).errors
```

Which will fail if there were errors saving your object (perhaps a validation), and show you the value of the errors object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rails 3.2.13, and it seems like assert_nil doesn't work properly as stated in the previous answer.

This is what worked for me:

```
assert_empty assigns(:user).errors
```

I believe this is because even a successful "save" call returns an ActiveRecord:Errors object containing with an Empty hash of "messages" so you could also do this:

```
assert_empty assigns(:user).errors.messages
```